# NMR spectroscopy

Tags: spectroscopy, magnetic-moment, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I was wondering how many times larger is the magnetic moment of an electron compared to a proton? How come the electrons magnetic moment play no role in NMR and MRI? Edit Electron Spin Spectroscopy exists

[image: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Figure-A1-Precession-of-a-magnetic-dipole-in-a-magnetic-field-The-external-magnetic_fig21_48375299]

I see how the average magnetic moment is pointing upwards with time but once an RF field has excited the spin it would look like this:

[image: https://www.slideserve.com/barrett-mayer/section4-an-assembly-of-non-interacting-spins]

which would still add up to being vertical or zero.
Unless the special case
[image]

Is this what they mean by the RF pulse only working on interacting spins not non interacting spins?

Comment: Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_magnetic_moment and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment ?

Comment: The electron has magnetic moment which is opposite to the spin, and the proton has a magnetic moment which is in the direction of the spin. Both the electrons and protons precess in the magnetic field at the same Larmor frequency with slightly higher populations in the low energy spin state. The difference is the frequency of the electromagnetic pulse needed to excite the spins - for the electron is on the order of $28$ GHz and for proton it's on the order of $40$ MHz. $40$ MHz is in the RF frequency band.

Comment: i thought the Larmor frequency was given by $$ \omega = -\gamma B $$ with the gyromagnetic ratio for an electron being 28000 MHz/T and that of a proton being 42 MHz/T thus the larmor frequency of an electron is 660 times larger. Also could you explain what you mean by "The difference is the frequency of the electromagnetic pulse needed to excite the spins" what is the difference you speak of

Comment: Are these diagrams you made? If not, then please credit the authors. Please also reduce the size to about half of this, because otherwise it's very difficult to read your question without excessive scrolling.

Comment: By the difference do you mean the difference in energy between the spin in the excited state and the ground state? that energy must be the energy of the photon

Comment: Relevant: [Electron Paramagnetic Resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_paramagnetic_resonance). It's perfectly possible to use electrons for magnetic resonance, so long as they're unpaired (which isn't *that* frequent, particularly in chemical species that are stable and inert enough to be biologically relevant). They don't show up on NMR because the resonance frequencies are different.

Comment: I see the magnetic moment of an electron is 9.284764×10−24 J/T so the difference in energy between spins is 2*9.284764×10−24 J/T and the frequency of absorption is 2*9.284764×10−24/h or 28GHz

Answer (score 1):

Mass of the proton is nearly 1837 times heavies than the mass of electron and hence the electronic magnetic moment is greater that the nuclear magnetic moment by this ratio.

It is not true, electrons play no role in NMR, conversely they are paramount because the main information we obtain in a NMR spectrum is the *chemical shift* that comes directly for the effects of the electron density on the nucleus.

The magnetic field the nucleus experiences differs slightly from the applied field, $B_0$ , because the magnetic field at the nucleus is shielded by the electron density surrounding the nucleus. This shielding is due to precession of electrons under the influence of the applied magnetic field. This precession generates an additional magnetic field that usually opposes the externally
applied magnetic field. The local magnetic field strength at the nucleus is given by:

$B = (1 - \sigma) · B_0$

As the electron density around the nucleus increases, the effective field decreases, leading to lower resonance frequencies. Since the resonance frequency is due to the chemical environment of the nuclear spin, the observed frequency is referred to as a
*chemical shift*.